# How to run react (using webpack) as a chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, webpack

I am building a chrome extension, but I want to use react to build it. I am not sure how I need to configure my `manifest.json` in order to get it to work.

This is my `manifest.json` file...

```
{
  "name": "Get pages source",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get pages source from a popup",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "./src/index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Now the way that I run my app locally, is with the following script in `package.json`...

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"
 }
```

My app displays on `localhost:8080`. However, I want the app to open up when I click on my extension. How can I do this? Do I need to reference the path to the localhost?

At the moment, when I run my extension, the `index.html` file gets loaded but nothing is rendered. Can someone explain how to do this?

EDIT

I also tried the following but it did not work...

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "http://localhost:8080/src/index.html"
 },
```

Comment: Extensions should include all the code and pages like popup in the package locally, otherwise you'd have to use an iframe. There are many examples of that.

Comment: Is your Chrome Extension only going to work on **your** computer? Or is this something you want to ship to the Chrome Web Store?

Comment: @wOxxOm what do you mean include it in the package? As in include them in my manifest file?

Comment: Note that if you continue using localhost in your extension than it wont work in other people's computer as they wouldn't have a server set up. Instead include link to minified js file in index.html and test your app using file://path/index.html instead of localhost:8080

Comment: @Dhyey its ok if it doesnt work on other peoples computers, at least for now. But I can't even get it to work locally. I tried the approach above but it did not work. Is my approach the way it is usually done?

Comment: @Balboa can you give the link to google drive or any other site with just hello world version of your extension, than maybe I can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change default_popup in manifest.json to "src/index.html".

Always build your code before packing extension and use *webpack* instead of *webpack-dev-server*

Also babel-core and webpack-dev-server were missing from package.json

Here is the screenshot of working extension:

[image]

Screenshot of development:

[image]

Make a new folder when you publish your extension which excludes node_modules folders ( only after you *npm run build* )

Here is the link with the updated code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByrxEyIevnFmNXlDZERaRTBMSlE

Please don't forget to run npm install and npm run build before loading unpacked extension.

Comment if any further help needed.